# TemplateDoesNotExist in Django (1.9)

Tags: django, templates

I have installed in a local development environment (vagrant box/ubuntu trusty) a Django project which uses several applications all loaded properly in the settings.py file.

When I try to run the application (python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000) I get:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
geodash/maps/base.yml


Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/vagrant/sparc2.git/sparc2/templates/geodash/maps/base.yml (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/vagrant/.venvs/sparc2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/geodash/maps/base.yml (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/vagrant/.venvs/sparc2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/geodash/maps/base.yml (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/vagrant/.venvs/sparc2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/templates/geodash/maps/base.yml (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/vagrant/.venvs/sparc2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pinax_theme_bootstrap/templates/geodash/maps/base.yml (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/vagrant/.venvs/sparc2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_forms_bootstrap/templates/geodash/maps/base.yml (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/vagrant/.venvs/sparc2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autocomplete_light/templates/geodash/maps/base.yml (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/vagrant/.venvs/sparc2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/leaflet/templates/geodash/maps/base.yml (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/vagrant/sparc2.git/sparc2/templates/geodash/maps/base.yml (Source does not exist)
```

The expected indeed doesnt exist in any of these paths. But it does exist in another folder which have this path:

```
/home/vagrant/geodash-framework-django.git/geodash/templates/geodash/maps
```

How do I include this in my settings.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `settings.py` and add the required directory in:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    # ...
    {
        'DIRS': 'the/path/to/the/required/directory',
    },
    # ...
]
```

EDIT: regarding your comment

If the app is added to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` and has the custom tags in a directory `templatetags`, then you should be able to load them in the template using something like this:

```
{% load my_custom_templatetag %}
```

If this doesn't work, try to specify the templatetags library in the `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    # ...
    {
        'DIRS': 'the/path/to/the/required/directory',
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ...
            'libraries': 'my_app.templatetags.my_custom_templatetag',
        },
    },
    # ...
]
```

Replace `my_app` with the app name and `my_custom_templatetag` with the name of the tag.

Comment: This seemed like it worked for now but I get another error: 'geodash_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of: ..

Comment: thanks mate. But it seems that the app geodash can not be found. Although it is defined in the settings.py file I get this error: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'geodash.templatetags.geodash_tags': No module named templatetags.geodash_tags

Comment: This is how I defined it: 'libraries':{
            'geodash_tags': 'geodash.templatetags.geodash_tags',
            }

Comment: I'm afraid I can't diagnose the problem from here. Is `geodash` really installed and available in your project, not just added to `INSTALLED_APPS`?